# Which patents were involved in Apple v. Samsung?

Tags: patent-infringement, apple, samsung, usd604305

Can someone list which patents Apple sued Samsung over? I believe one of them was rounded corners on a mobile device. I could be wrong though, but if I am correct about that one, then any mobile device you can possibly think of is prior art.

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking that Apple/Samsung have had multiple court brawls over patents? As such would you mind adding a context like date period?

Answer (score 18):

### List of Patents

This appears to be the guts of the billion dollar suite:

- [Patent Application #US20080168404](http://www.google.com/patents/US7469381) "rubber-banding" patent: Yes for all devices.
- [Patent Application #US20080168384](http://www.google.com/patents/US7844915) 
  "pinch-to-zoom" patent: Yes for all devices except for Intercept
  and Replenish smartphones.
- [Patent Application #US20080094368](http://www.google.com/patents/US7864163) "tap-to-zoom" patent: Yes for Droid Charge, Epic 4G, Exhibit 4G,
  Fascinate, Ace, Prevail, Galaxy S, Galaxy S 4G, S II AT&T, i9100, S
  II T-Mobile, Galaxy Tab, Tab 10.1, Infuse 4G, Mesmerize and
  Replenish. No for Captivate, Continuum, Gem, Indulge, Intercept,
  Nexus S 4G, Transform, and Vibrant.
- D'667 iPhone design patent: Yes for SEC's Fascinate, Galaxy S, Galaxy
  S 4G, Galaxy S II for AT&T, Galaxy S II i9100, Galaxy S II for
  T-Mobile, Galaxy S II Epic 4G Touch, Skyrocket, Showcase, Infuse 4G,
  Mesmerize and Vibrant. No for Ace. Yes for STA's Galaxy S 4G, Galaxy
  S II for T-Mobile, Galaxy S II Epic 4G Touch, Skyrocket, Showcase,
  Infuse 4G, Mesmerize, and Vibrant.
- D'087 iPhone design patent: Yes for SEC's S i9000, Galaxy S 4G, and
  Vibrant.  No for Galaxy S II ATT, S II i9100, Epic 4G Touch,
  Skyrocket and Infuse 4G. Yes for STA's S 4G and Vibrant only.
- D'305 iPhone home screen design patent: Yes for SEC's Captivate,
  Continuum, Droid Charge, Epic 4G, Fascinate, Galaxy S i9000, Galaxy S
  4G, Showcase, Gem, Indulge, Infuse 4G, Mesmerize and Vibrant. Yes for
  STA's Captivate, Continuum, Chrarge, Epic 4G, Fascinate, Galaxy S 4G,
  Gem, Indulge, Infuse 4G, Mesmerize and Vibrant.
- D'889 iPad design patent: No for all devices

#### References

- [Apple Insider: Samsung guilty of patent infringement, Apple awarded nearly $1.05B](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/08/24/jury_reaches_verdict_in_apple_v_samsung_trial.html)

#### Comment

Google index's US Patents but I couldn't find one for the rounded corners:

https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=inassignee:%22Apple+Inc.%22

> It would depend on how broadly the Patent is written. The main job
>   of a Patent Attorney is to write the application to encompass as much as
>   possible. However I highly doubt it could embody 'any rounded corner
>   on a phone'. It has to be technology, a manufacturing process, a
>   formula & etc - rounded corners would come under a registered design.

Its D '305 patent:

> Jumping to the user interface, the D '305 patent centers on a grid of
>   rounded square icons against a black background.

Comment: You may be interested in: http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/72/345

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking that Apple/Samsung have had multiple court brawls over patents? As such would you mind adding dates and context to the patent list?

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57500273-37/apple-v-samsung-the-infringing-device-scorecard/) are the Apple patents either claimed or proved to be infringed by Samsung.

Here's a list of them with brief description:

### ['381 patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US7469381?dq=apple+7469381&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_UFdUNG4LY_rrQea1ICgDQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA)

> Besides the "rubber band" effect where a page "bounces" when a user scrolls to the bottom, '381 also includes touch-screen actions like dragging documents and multi-touch capabilities like pinch to zoom and twist to rotate.

---

### ['915 patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US7844915?printsec=abstract&dq=apple+7844915&ei=ekJdUJaqB43wrQeG9IDwDg#v=onepage&q=apple%207844915&f=false)

> Also a touch-screen patent, '915 relates to a device capable of distinguishing between a single-touch scroll operation and a multi-touch pinch-to-zoom operation.

---

### ['163 patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US7864163?printsec=abstract&dq=apple+7864163&ei=1kJdUMPlAY7yrQeV1YGwCw#v=onepage&q=apple%207864163&f=false)

> You know how you can double-tap a touch screen to enlarge and center portions of Web page, photo, or document? That's what this patent covers. The jury found that the Intercept did not violate patents '915 or '163.

---

### [D '677 patent](http://www.google.com/patents/USD618677?printsec=abstract&dq=apple+D677&ei=E0NdULzyKs_nrAf8tIHICw#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Switching to hardware, D '677 relates to the front face of an electronic device, as embodied by the iPhone.

---

### [D '087 patent](http://www.google.com/patents/USD593087?printsec=abstract&dq=apple+D+%27087&ei=PENdUOeRDojirAf8woCQCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Similar to D '677, the D '087 patent concerns the general outline or "ornamental" design of a phone.

---

### [D '305 patent](http://www.google.com/patents/USD604305?printsec=abstract&dq=apple+D+%27305&ei=bENdUKP7JMXIrQfQ94DgBA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> The D '305 patent centers on a grid layout having rounded square icons and a color scheme. (Note: [the actual filing is in color](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2013/08/06/strong-design-patents-the-power-of-color/id=44342/))

---

### [D '889 patent](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=D504,889.PN.&OS=PN/D504,889&RS=PN/D504,889)

> For the final patent, which relates to the industrial design of a tablet computer, the jury found that neither Wi-Fi nor the 4G LTE versions of the Galaxy Tab 10.1 infringed.

Comment: how can you get a patent on a grid of rounded square icons against a black background? Thats just illogical. They should have just gone ahead and claimed rectangles, triangles, hexagons and octagons with all combinations of colors. Even those combinations put together how is this novel or inventive? This just represents a design/implementation/idea on a kind of user interface. I don't get it.

Comment: I don't get it either! A lot of narrow claims went into the grant of patents in the first place and I think a lot of lobbying went into the $ 1 Billion jury decision. Apple didn't win against Samsung anywhere in the world except for the US, which is a good pointer to how outdated the USPTO screening process actually is!

Comment: and Samsung will appeal(outside of apples back door) and win most of that money back. The jurors even admitted that they didnt want to look through the claims too thoroughly. we need to look at a lot of these for the USPTO to look at again. no one should be getting patents on shapes, regardless of use, technological or not.

Comment: Could you link to the patents in question? That would make your post much easier to follow on.

Comment: Sure...edited...

Comment: I'm certainly not comfortable with not only Apple owning these patents, but also suing left and right with claims of infringement. That's just absurd.

Comment: My jaw dropped when I saw the grid of icons patent. These do not deserve to be granted.

Comment: Design patents - distinct front "normal" utility patents - is all about shapes and other ornamental aspects.